# RSA library with angular

Tags: node.js, angular, encryption

Hello I am trying to implement encryption in my application. I am using angular (angular-4) for the frontend and node js for the backend. Communication is done through socket.io through custom commands. But basically what I am stuck at is finding an appropriate library for RSA encryption in client side. client will first request server for an RSA public key. Server responds with key but now I cannot find any library suitable to encrypt data with RSA using this public key. I have tried node-rsa. Following is a code sn

```
import * as NodeRSA from 'node-rsa';

@Injectable()

export class SecurityService {
    RSA: any
    initializeRSA(key: string) {
        this.RSA = new NodeRSA();
        this.RSA.importKey(key)
        console.log(this.RSA.encrypt('Hello World'));
    }
```

But I am receiving this error.

```
Error during encryption. Original error: TypeError: crypt.createHash is not a function
at NodeRSA.webpackJsonp.../../../../node-rsa/src/NodeRSA.js.module.exports.NodeRSA.$$encrypt
```

Help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I am not quite sure, but this that you do is back end Javascript and I assume you need front end Javascript library. Try this one https://github.com/travist/jsencrypt

Comment: I used this for one of my project https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-js

Comment: Find demo here https://plnkr.co/edit/Oh2iLZGhFskyvXBChXRE?p=preview

Comment: @Yatinpatel crypto-js does not provide RSA encryption

Comment: @theadnangondal give me 5 min :) Give you new link

Comment: @theadnangondal Updated link jsfiddle.net/ygd8wpq0

Comment: @Yatinpatel please put this link to answer. I will accept this for an answer. Thank you very much

Comment: @theadnangondal Added Angular Plunker for better understanding

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Please Find Solution Plunker here:

JSEncrypt with angular

https://plnkr.co/edit/sEPK1DcynMphJnGziUVX

I have used JSEncrypt v2.3.0 Lib for same.

**Implementation**

Add JSEncrypt Lib javascript file in Asset Folder of Angular Project.
Add script in `index.html`

`<script src="jsencrypt.js"></script>`

So, It will available at all Component.

declare JSEncrypt at your component file where you want to use it.

`declare var JSEncrypt: any;`

Inside class declare variable

```
decrypt = new JSEncrypt();
const privatekey = Private Key goes here;
const publickey = Public key goes here;
const decryptDataRow = Decrypted data string;
this.decrypt.setPrivateKey(privatekey);
this.decryptdata = this.decrypt.decrypt(decryptDataRow);
```

`decryptdata` contain result string

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Hello @yatin-patel.
When I use JSEncrypt in Angular it encrypts data perfectly with a shared public key but when decrypting it in java with the private key it gives me unreadable chars.
can you help me?

Comment: RSA with `node-forge` plugin in angular example 

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-4-template-4zsmzy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhome%2Fhome.page.ts

Answer (score 4):

I used CryptoJS for AES encoding. And, node-forge for RSA encoding.

Part 1: 
`npm install --save node-forge`
`npm install --save crypto-js`
`npm install --save @types/crypto-js`
`npm install --save @types/node-forge`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as forge from 'node-forge';
import * as CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';

/*
* forge: For RSA encryption
* CryptoJS: For AES encryption
*/
export interface AESKeys {
    iv: string;
    key: string;
}

@Injectable()
export class MyEncryptService {

    constructor() {}
    /**
     * @param randomWordArray
     * AES Key or IV generated in this service as Hex string
     * @param pemKey
     * the Public Key from "get_rsa_key" endpoint (separate http service)
     * @returns
     * a RSA encrypted random key/iv
     */
    public getBase64Encrypted(randomWordArray, pemKey): string {
        const pk = forge.pki.publicKeyFromPem(pemKey);
        return forge.util.encode64(pk.encrypt(forge.util.hexToBytes(randomWordArray)));
    }

    /**
     * @param text
     * field input text
     * @param randomKey
     * random key generated from word array
     * @param randomIv
     * random iv generated from word array
     * @returns
     * encrypted text
     */
    public encrypted(text, randomKey, randomIv): string {
        const cipherText: any = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(text, randomKey, {
            iv: randomIv,
            mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
            padding: CryptoJS.pad.NoPadding
        });
        return cipherText.toString();
    }

    /**
     * @param wordLength
     * normally: IV = 16 or Key = 32
     * @returns
     * randomly generated 128bit (IV) or 256bit (Key) word array
     */
    public getWordArray(wordLength): string {
        return CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(wordLength);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do if you want to stay with the very good node-rsa library it to eject ng-cli from your project and configure webpack to automatically polyfill the nodejs crypto module with the crypto-browserify library.

First, eject ng-cli from your project (you will need to run `yarn build` or `npm run build` to build your project and you won't be able anymore to use `ng build`) :

```
ng eject
```

Then you need to add this data to the `webpack.config.js` file created by the ejection process :

```
"node": {
    ...
    "crypto": true,
    ...
}
```

This will tell webpack to polyfill the `crypto` module.

I will soon dive into how to keep `ng-cli` and have a correct polyfilling behavior...