# Ionic 3 - Use jsencrypt

Tags: angularjs, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm trying to hash my passwords for login on my Ionic 3 app. I found some tutorial about jsencrypt but it doesn't work and i don't really understand how it work...

Here what i did :

`npm install --save jsencrypt`

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ApiDatabaseService } from '../../providers/api-database-service';
import Encrypt from 'jsencrypt';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-Login',
  templateUrl: 'Login.html'
})

@Injectable()

export class LoginPage {

  private prem: string = `my_key`;
  Users:any = []; // Here there is all my users 

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public serviceOne: ApiDatabaseService) {
    this.serviceOne.getDataUser().subscribe( // I'm calling my api to acces to my database
            data => this.Users = data
        );
  }

  public create(name: string): string { // Here the password should be encrypt
        let encrypt = new Encrypt.JSEncrypt();
        encrypt.setPublicKey(this.pem);
        return encrypt.encrypt(name);
    };
}
```

And i have this error :

`Typescript Error
Property 'pem' does not exist on type 'LoginPage'.`

Also, for Ionic 2 there is many documentation like this : https://docs.ionic.io/services/auth/. But nothing for Ionic 3, why ?

Comment: `prem`, `pem` -- typo?

Comment: That's true ...

Comment: Do you know how it this function work ?

Comment: Please check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44887294/rsa-library-with-angular/44889432#44889432

Answer (score 2):

Change the line

```
encrypt.setPublicKey(this.pem);
```

To

```
encrypt.setPublicKey(this.prem);
```

Answer (score 1):

When using the Ionic service your app sends your plain password to the Ionic with service when creating and logging into your account. The auth service will handling all the encryption.

Also, there are no separate docs for Ionic 3 as it is essential the same as Ionic 2 except for some new features and big fixes. There are a few breaking changes but not many. It's not a full rewrite like there was going from Ionic 1 -> Ionic 2 and they are now using semantic versioning so major releases will be more regular similar to Angular.

Answer (score 1):

change

```
private prem: string = `my_key`;
```

to

```
`private pre: string = `my_key`;
```

Answer (score 1):

change the line

```
private prem: string = `my_key`;
```

to

```
private pem: string = `my_key`;
```