# Ad-Hoc SSL in Angular (and backend)

Tags: angularjs, ssl, encryption, public-key-encryption, encryption-asymmetric

Most of the frontend web frameworks are just a few years old, and are rapidly changing. Are there any recent JS packages or libraries that do SSL very well?

It can cost quite a bit of money to enable SSL with cloud hosting platforms, registrars, etc.

Whatever private keys our browsers use for their typical SSL behavior should be accessible to a javascript app running in that browser, no?

The ideal situation would be to encode information within Javascript so that, on the backend server, in some backend framework, it was indistinguishable (from a developer's perspective) from standard browser-implemented SSL.

SO has some posts about it, but none of them are very recent. [This SO post has perspectives from 2011 through 2014](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1150/encrypting-and-obscuring-data-between-site-user-without-ssl), and [this SO post from circa 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44887294/rsa-library-with-angular).

If someone built something that did this in Javascript, then, for example, ideally, an Angular app could incorporate it by putting something in `app.config()` regarding `$routeProvider` or `$httpProvider`

Comment: It seems like "[Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/integration-guide/)" is out there doing this, and is maintained by Linux Foundation. Has anyone implemented this in, say, a Javascript app utilizing backend endpoints served by a common framework (Django, Flask, Node, Rails)?

Comment: "should be accessible to a javascript " no that would be serious security breach.  even the browsers are using system libraries for ssl. All client-side frameworks I am aware use underlaying browser to connect (thr browser won't allow anything else). for server side - its all about system libs. ssl is very difficult to do correctly with all supported options. so - what is exactly your question?

Comment: Stackoverflow is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum. You're suppose to ask a programming question that's narrow enough for someone to provide a correct answer.

Comment: Hey @gusto2, thanks for the response. I accept that SSL is very difficult, but so are several things that client-side frameworks do (at least from my perspective). I'm surprised nobody does this.