# Encrypt Image in c# and decrypt in typescript

Tags: c#, angular, typescript

Am new to angular 2. I would like to encrypt my image with secret key in c# and decrypt it in typescript. Is that possible. If yes can anyone help me out.
Thanks in advance.

Code to encrypt

```
public string EncryptImage(byte[] imageBytes)
    {
        var csp = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048);

        var privKey = csp.ExportParameters(true);

        var pubKey = csp.ExportParameters(false);


        string pubKeyString;
        {
            var sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();

            var xs = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(RSAParameters));

            xs.Serialize(sw, pubKey);

            pubKeyString = sw.ToString();

        }
        {
            var sr = new System.IO.StringReader(pubKeyString);

            var xs = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(RSAParameters));

            pubKey = (RSAParameters)xs.Deserialize(sr);
        }

        csp = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
        csp.ImportParameters(pubKey);

        var bytesCypherText = csp.Encrypt(imageBytes, false);

        var cypherText = Convert.ToBase64String(bytesCypherText);

        return cypherText;
    }
```

Getting error at

```
    var bytesCypherText = csp.Encrypt(imageBytes, false);
```

as bad length

Comment: _"would like to encrypt my image with secret key"_ You _encrypt_ with the public key and _decrypt_ with the secret key, usually. But what makes you think you need this?

Answer (score 1):

Encrypting in C#

```
public string EncryptData(string imageBytesBase64, string Encryptionkey)
    {
        RijndaelManaged objrij = new RijndaelManaged();

        objrij.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

        objrij.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

        byte[] keyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Encryptionkey);

        byte[] ivBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Encryptionkey.Substring(0, 16));

        int len = keyBytes.Length;

        if (len > ivBytes.Length)
            len = ivBytes.Length;

        Array.Copy(keyBytes, ivBytes, len);

        objrij.Key = keyBytes;

        objrij.IV = ivBytes;

        ICryptoTransform objtransform = objrij.CreateEncryptor();

        byte[] textDataByte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(imageBytesBase64);

        return Convert.ToBase64String(objtransform.TransformFinalBlock(textDataByte, 0, textDataByte.Length));

    }
```

Descrypt in TypeScript

```
var decryptedTxt = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encryptedText, key, {
        keySize: 128 / 8,
        iv: iv,
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
        padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
    });

    this.decryptedText = decryptedTxt.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8)

    this.ImageSrc = 'data:image/jpg;base64,' + this.decryptedText;
```

Here Encryptionkey in c# and key in typescript are same

Answer (score -1):

Hello you can use any Crypto engine in both side.

For exemple you can use:

## RSA (Public / Private Key)

**For TypeScript side :**
[RSA library with angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44887294/rsa-library-with-angular)

**For C# Side :**
[C# RSA encryption/decryption with transmission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17128038/c-sharp-rsa-encryption-decryption-with-transmission)

## AES (Password) :

**For typescript side :**
use https://github.com/ricmoo/aes-js and just do :

`import 'aes-js'; declare var aesjs: any;`

**For C# side :**
More information here [Using AES encryption in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273452/using-aes-encryption-in-c-sharp)

Because all crypto algo have many configuration parameter, be careful to have matching configuration in C# and Typescript side.

Comment: hello sir, i have added my code. Used RSA encryption, but am getting am error