# How to encrypt data with RSA in Angular using C# generated key

Tags: c#, angular, public-key-encryption

I have a frontend in angular and a backend in C#. I generated a pair of keys (XML format) and I want to use the public key to encrypt some data in the frontend and send it to the backend where I'll decrypt it. However, I couldn't use any of the libraries/modules that I found on the internet. Does anyone know a good library that I can use? If you could also provide an example, it would be great!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found node-forge which was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44887294/rsa-library-with-angular/44889432) and managed to put it working. For node-forge, I needed to export my public key in the PEM format. For such thing, I used [this code](https://gist.github.com/therightstuff/aa65356e95f8d0aae888e9f61aa29414)
and then I loaded the key and encrypted my data just like this  (on angular)

```
let rsa = forge.pki.publicKeyFromPem("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----"+
    "MIIBI..."+
    "-----END PUBLIC KEY-----");

return window.btoa(rsa.encrypt(data));
```